# Get selected object if model is set to property

Tags: angularjs, ng-options

I have the following code:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="form.ProtocolId" data-ng-options="protocol.ProtocolId as protocol.Name for protocol in protocols" required />
```

Where a protocol has this structure:

```
[{ "ProtocolId": 1, "Name": "Protocol 1", "Description": "A description for protocol 1" }]
```

In $scope.form I am setting the ProtocolId, which is what I need to submit the form.  But I would like to show the description of the Protocol to the user when they select it.  Sort of like `{{selectedProtocol.Description}}`.  Except I don't have a `selectedProtocol` as I'm only selecting the id.

Is there a way to get the actual selected Protocol here?  I could write a method to track the change of a selected Protocol and then in my controller set the form.ProtocolId, but I wonder if there is a simpler way...

Comment: What you can do is select by the protocol itself (ie, `data-ng-options="protocol as protocol.Name for protocol in protocols"`) which allows you easy access to the description: `{{form.Protocol.Description}}`. And when you submit, extract the id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tend not to use the `ng-options` directive for `select` just because there is usually something else I want to do as well...

```
<select class="form-control" ng-model="form.protocol" required>
    <option ng-repeat="protocol in protocols" value="protocol">{{protocol.Name}}</option>
</select>
<div ng-show="form.protocol.Description">{{form.protocol.Description}}</div>
```

Now when a selection is made `form.protocol` is set with the JS object for the selected protocol.  You can manipulate it later to just send the `form.protocol.ProtocolID` upon submit.

Comment: This is interesting- it gives a bit more flexibility on how you manipulate the selected object which is nice.

Comment: True. I usually find that I'll need to use more of the information contained in the selection then just a particular field's value. Rather than going through looking for the information later on within the array of objects - I know I have a variable set to the selected object that I can use instead.  Saves a bit of time.

Answer (score 0):

So I marked the ngRepeat option as an answer, but I ended up not using it for several reasons: primary being that my list values were not populated correctly in my form with angularjs due to my model structure.  What DID work however was this:

```
<select class="form-control" data-ng-model="form.PrimaryProtocolId" data-ng-options="protocol.ProtocolId as primaryDisplayName(protocol) for protocol in primaryprotocols" required />
```

Where `primaryDisplayName()` is a method on my $scope that gives me the format I need:

```
$scope.primaryProtocolName = function(protocol) {
    return protocol.Name + " (" + protocol.ProtocolType.Name + ")";
};
```